# Find ImageControl using databound event in DevExpress gridView

Tags: gridview, devexpress, databound

I am displaying a image in ASPX GridView based on some criteria. I am unable to find the Imagebutton control from server side. I am using DataBound event to capture the value of Imagebutton.

Please look at the code snippet.

```
ASPX:  

 <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Active" FieldName="Active" Name="Active" >
         <DataItemTemplate>
              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBell" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetImageName(Eval("Active"))%>' />
         </DataItemTemplate>
 </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>

Code behind:

Protected Sub gvAlertReport_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles gvAlertReport.DataBound

  'Here I need to find control of Image button "imgBell"

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this your question here:

[Find ASPX GridView Image control from Server side](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q326552)